# Academia logo isn't showing up on Hot Questions list

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

but it works fine on the hot questions sidebar:

[image]

Please excuse my horrible skills at freehand trapezoids.

Possibly related to caching? It'd be cool if the admins could do something about this

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: Try getting the url of the favicon, display it and do a hard refresh to get your local cache to update.

Comment: @ChrisF I did that, the old logo is still showing

Comment: Damn. Then I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: FWIW, it is likely the favicon.ico for academia ( used in the network activity - http://cdn.sstatic.net/academia/img/favicon.ico ) and http://cdn.sstatic.net/academia/img/icon-48.png (used in the hot list page) that need to be updated.  The hot questions on the side works from a different source (appears to be a huge list of sprites and some stylesheet magic).  I still blame caching... because.

Comment: It *is* caching, but it's the caching that the CDN does not your browser. Until the CDN refreshes *its* cache, this is gonna look old.

Comment: @SHOG9 Could you change this to status-completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guys and gals, looks like it was fixed and never explicitly mentioned here...

[image]